# Market Research Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I work at a startup and we're doing a lot of online market research to get data about supermarkets in Germany, their name, address, telephone numbers, emails and so that already exist on their website or other places on the internet. my question is: Is there any algorithm that could help us do this job faster instead of doing it manually every single day? Like insert the name of the Supermarket chain and then let it do its thing?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I think "web scrapping" is the generic term relevant to what you are trying to do. You will probably have a decent amount of programming to do before having a tool that does exactly what you want. However, this question, as is, is not about Computer Science, so this is not the right place to ask it.

Comment: (@Tassle `scrapping` made my morning - may be the thing to do considering the state of web&world.) Please stick to what's [on-topic with COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), heeding [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @greybeard Oh thanks, now I know the number of p's matters here! (French native)